# Decode Using Base64 Not Working In Unit Tests For PowerMockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, powermockito

How can I write unit tests to work with Base64 decoding?

I have the following test

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(Log::class)
class JwtDeserializerTest {

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Log::class.java) // this helped with Runtime exception for having Log in my code
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Base64::class.java)
    }

    @Test
    fun testJwtToken() {
        val jwt = Jwt(jwt_token)
        val expirationDateTimeFromJwtClaims = jwt.getClaim("exp")?.asLong() ?: 0L
        assertTrue(expirationDateTimeFromJwtClaims != 0L)
    }
}
```

The conflict comes when the following code is ran internally for instantiating the Jwt object.

```
fun decodeFromBase64(value: String): String {
    try {
        val data = Base64.decode(value, Base64.DEFAULT)
        if (data != null) {
            return String(data, charset("UTF-8"))
        }
    } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.message, e)
    }
    return ""
}
```

During instantiation, I decode the JWT token and setup some helper methods while examining the claims. This includes checking how many parts the token has e.g. header, payload, signature and more.

While debugging, decoding causes an issue. I had a similar issue with the Log function, but adding `PowerMockito.mockStatic(Log::class.java)` resolved that conflict.

How can I resolve this for Base64? Decoding always returns null. However, when tested outside of junit test, I receive the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you running into the same issue, the solutions you find online aren't so simple. Many suggest using PowerMockito. As it turns out, it is much easier to use `RobolectricTestRunner`

I made the following change and everything now works perfectly.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class JwtDeserializerTest {

    @Test
    fun testJwtToken() {
        val jwt = Jwt(jwt_token)
        val expirationDateTimeFromJwtClaims = jwt.getClaim("exp")?.asLong() ?: 0L
        assertTrue(expirationDateTimeFromJwtClaims != 0L)
    }
}
```

No need for setup() method. No need to worry about which specific version of PowerMockito to use because some versions have bugs and others do not. Was really easy. Cheers!